# C# playback of Vimeo videos

Tags: c#, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm looking for a way to stream Vimeo videos using my C# application.  At the moment I am playing back videos locally using a Windows Media Player widget in a Windows Forms application.

I suppose I could use a WebBrowser in Form window if I had to, but am looking for something a bit more native than that if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the Windows Media Player control was able to play back Vimeo links directly.

A Vimeo Pro account is required in order to get the links to videos that can be used to stream videos using "3rd party players".